# ng-include not displaying included table

Tags: angularjs, html

HTML script

```
<div>
  <select ng-model="selectView">
    <option value="empTable.html">Table View</option>
    <option value="empList.html">List View</option>
  </select>

  <div ng-include="selectView"></div>

</div>
```

Angular script

```
var angScript = angular.module("multiselectapp",[]). controller ("multicontroller", function ($scope){
var empList = [ 
  { name:"sue", gender:"female" },
  { name:"Joe", gender:"male" }
];

$scope.employees =empList;
$scope. selectView ="empTable.html";
});
```

The `empTable.html`  and `empList.html` has basic HTML script using `ng-repeat` to display the table and list view.
The angular script file is loaded and all paths are good to go having cross verified them with a `$scope.message="file detected in html“` message which is displayed on HTML page. 
But the table and list is not displayed at all.

Suggestions please!

Comment: try `<div ng-include="'{selectView}'"></div>`

Comment: Check your network tab it should be requesting the HTML. Check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wOrpWF4L7D8eawzWaC5g?p=preview).

Comment: @Manish did not work

Comment: check console. Network tab. See if any 404 for that template

Comment: Please log {{selectView}} in the template to see if it is the value you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
 Ng-include=" '{{selectedView}}' "
```

if its not gonna work try removing {{}}

Comment: both did not work, selectView is a scope property so I suppose it is to be directly used in double quotes.

Comment: Can u try to manually add the html path rather than using angularjs var. If this doesnt work the problem is on your path not on ur code

Comment: Ng-include=" 'empTable.html' "

Comment: By the way you can use scope property in many ways its called interpolation or binding in angular. Doest always mean u use it with double qoutes only

Comment: Then if thats the case i suggest you check ur ng-repeat that might be the cause why theres no data displaying.

Comment: Arnold ng-repeat is good.. Tried it individually in another script, also the ' list' is not displaying ..

Comment: I see, i think you are the one that can solve this problem because you said ng-include=" 'empTable.html' " is not working in the first place so i suggest u check ur pathing have a good day and goodluck :)

Comment: Got  busy at office. @arnold i believe you are right as ng-include="'empTable.HTML'" does not display anything.So it has to an error in pathing. Also rest of the things are perfect. What Paths should Be Assigned?

Comment: Is there any errors showing on ur browser dev tools console? If pathing is the problem u can see those error over there

Answer (score 0):

Try out

```
<div ng-include src="selectView"></div>
```

Comment: check your template path

Comment: No difference between <ng-include src="url" and <div ng-include="url">

Comment: Then try to print value of this {{selectView}} to check it is assign with value or not.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it works for me:

https://embed.plnkr.co/wFaG4m?p=preview

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>selected item is : {{selectedItem}}</p>

    <p> name of selected item is : {{selectedItem.name}} </p>

    <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items"></select>
    <div ng-include="selectedItem.name"></div>
</body>

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
```

Js:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.items = [];
  $scope.selectedItem = { name: 'a.html'};
  $scope.items = [{name: 'c.html'},{ name: 'a.html'}];

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope. selectView ="empTable.html";
```

Here **unnecessary space is there** between `$scope` and the variable name. Try removing space as below `$scope.selectView ="empTable.html";`

Comment: I believe the error should be in paths as rest of things are fine, having tried in other scripts. What paths should be assigned becoz the respective files are all in the same folder?